# How to extend jQuery Library

Tags: jquery

I want to extend a particular aspect of jQuery UI: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.js

Search in the source code for `easeInElastic` to see the following snippet:

```
easeInElastic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c; alert('');
    if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*9.3;
    if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
    else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
    return -(a*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )) + b;
},
```

I need to slightly modify the code, but I don't want to duplicate the whole library.
How can I include a modified snippet in a separate .js file so that it will overwrite the original?

**Edit:**

Out of all the suggested methods, this is the only one that worked:

```
$.extend($.easing,
{
    easeInElastic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
           alert('');
        var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
        if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*.3;
        if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
        else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
        return -(a*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )) + b;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.fn.easeInElastic = function(x,t,b,c,d){...}
```

Or use `$.extend();`

Answer (score 3):

Overwrite that particular method with your own.

```
$.easing.easeInElastic = function(...
```

As long as your additional .js file with that code is placed after the jqueryui.js, it will overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery documentation has a page on plugins/extensions:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Basically, it's a matter of extending `$.fn`.